# set a value based on loc and iloc

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe

```
df

a   b   c
t  -2   8
l   5   4
t   3   9
t   2   6
l  -2   7
t  -1   3
```

I need to modiy a cell based first on a filtering on the a column and than on a poistion.
so for instance:

```
for i in df.a.unique():
    j=0
    while ((j< len(df[df.a==i])) and(df.loc[df.a==i, 'b'].iloc[j]<0)):
          df.loc[df.a==i, 'b'].iloc[j] = 0
df = df[df.b!=0]
```

The desired result will give

```
a   b   c
l   5   4
t   3   9
t   2   6
l   -2  7
t   -1  3
```

So, what I need is, for every unique element in a, I want to keep everything that comes after the first positive value of b for this a and drop.

The problem is, when I am using

```
df.loc[df.a==i, 'b'].iloc[j] = 0
```

This is not modifying the value of the cell.

Comment: can you show us what is your expected output?

Comment: It's under the desired result in my question. Actually it's a time series. So I need to keep the elements in this order. For each unique element in a I need to remove all the first results in b that are negative and only keep values that start from the first positive element in b.